# How do I test collection input in simple form using capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Am trying to test that input which has collection will be filled, am using simple form for my form and capybara with Rspec for the test.this is the input am trying to  fill 
`<%= f.input :number_of_beds, collection: House::NUMBEROFBEDS, label: false %>`.

House model has NUMBEROFBEDS which is an array like so:

```
class House < ApplicationRecord
  NUMBEROFBEDS = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
end
```

In my *spec/system/create_house_spec.rb*. I tried testing that I can fill in the number_of_beds input  like so:

```
require "rails_helper"
RSpec.describe "Create House" do
  scenario 'successful house creation' do 
    visit new_house_path
    fill_in 'house_number_of_beds', with: '1'
  end
end
```

But  I get the following error

```
  1) Create House successful bed creation
     Failure/Error: fill_in 'house_number_of_beds', with: '1'

     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "house_number_of_beds" that is not disabled
```

Comment: Don't you forget an `e` to `hous` in your path => `new_house_path` ?

Comment: Yeah thank that was just a typo when  I was typing this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collection option in simple form, works as `select tag`, therefore testing it with `fill_in` is failing the best approach would to use select i.e 
`select '1', from: 'house_number_of_beds'`